# Spring does not find beans generated by annotations

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-3

I want to retrieve from my spring context all beans that are of a certain class (or subclass). But this  only detects beans that are specifically defined by xml. Beans that are defined by annotations, such as `@Service`are not detected here. (Although inside the app they are detected, initialized, and autowired perfectly).

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("*-context.xml");
Map<String, DataUpdater> beans = ctx.getBeansOfType(MyClass.class, true, true);
// why are beans missing?
```

Comment: Does your `*-context.xml` file have a `<component-scan>` element?

Comment: yes, I have a component scan. and the annotated classes are detected, instantiated (per print in the constructor method) and autowired to other beans (per print in the setter method). But I cannot get them from the outside world.

Comment: You try search your bean exactly in XmlApplicationContext, but this context contain only beans declared in this xml. You must search in 
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JConfig.class);

Comment: @AlexeySviridov, no, I don't need annotationConfigApplicationContext because my main source for instantating beans is xml file. But some beans inside the xml (compnent-scan) file are instantiating other beans and those "second level" beans I can't seem to find.

Comment: @flybywire, oh i'm see now. In any way, i'm think your problem some - you search in exactly one context which contains only beans defined in it. But you must search in some global application context, that contains all resolved beans you define.i.e. see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, some stupid error... I was not properly loading my xml files, however beans were being instantiated as some background process was creating a parallel xml context with the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems and I never got `getBeansOfType()` to work correctly. My solution:

```
@Autowired
public void setMyClasses( List<MyClass> beans ) {
    ...
}
```

Spring will collect the list somehow and inject it. If you don't need to know when the list is injected, you can also inject it as a field:

```
@Autowired
private List<MyClass> beans;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must search your beans also in

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
```

If you want search in XmlContext and AnnotationContext you must combine them with

```
 @ImportResource("classpath:xmlcontext.xml")
```

In annotated config

Or you can try implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface and search in Context provided by it.